# How to change an HTML5 canvas to normal after grey scale conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am converting an HTML5 canvas image to grey scale with the following code. Now I need to revert it back to normal after converting to grey scale, on a button click. How can I do that?

Here is my code.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var data = imageData.data;
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
          var brightness = 0.34 * data[i] + 0.5 * data[i + 1] + 0.16 * data[i + 2];
          data[i] = brightness;
          // red
          data[i + 1] = brightness;
          // green
          data[i + 2] = brightness;
          // blue
          // i+3 is alpha (the fourth element)
        }
        context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: The simplest solution would probably be to just store imageData in a variable and later call context.putImageData using the stored imageData?

Comment: may I need to save var data = imageData.data; and assign data variable later ?